# Why is my widget not loading on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, widget, onupdate

So here is my `WidgetProvider`

```
    public class MessagesWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static final String EXTRA_WIDGET_MESSAGE = "widget_message";
    public static final String EXTRA_WIDGET_ID = "widget_id";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        updateWidget(context, appWidgetIds, appWidgetManager);
    }

    private static void updateWidget(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        ForwardingMessage[] allMessages = ForwardingMessage.getAllMessages();
        RemoteViews views = null;
        if (allMessages.length == 0) {
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.messages_widget_layout);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.profileNameTextView,
                    context.getString(R.string.no_messages_to_show));
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.messageContentTextView, "");
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
        } else {
            ForwardingMessage latestMessage = allMessages[allMessages.length - 1];
            for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
                views = generateViewsFromMessage(latestMessage, context, id);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, views);
            }
        }
    }

    private static RemoteViews generateViewsFromMessage(
            ForwardingMessage message, Context context, int widgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.messages_widget_layout);
        ForwardingMessage previous = message.getPreviousMessage();
        ForwardingMessage next = message.getNextMessage();
        views.setBoolean(R.id.previousButton, "setEnabled", previous != null);
        views.setBoolean(R.id.nextButton, "setEnabled", next != null);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.profileNameTextView, message
                .getForwardingProfile().getName());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.messageContentTextView, message.getText());
        // Let's start adding the listeners to the buttons
        if (previous != null) {
            Intent previousIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SHOW_WIDGET_MESSAGE);
            previousIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_WIDGET_MESSAGE, previous);
            previousIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_WIDGET_ID, widgetId);
            PendingIntent previousPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 0, previousIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                            | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.previousButton,
                    previousPendingIntent);
        }
        // Now the next message
        if (next != null) {
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SHOW_WIDGET_MESSAGE);
            nextIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_WIDGET_MESSAGE, next);
            nextIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_WIDGET_ID, widgetId);
            PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 1, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                            | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.nextButton, nextPendingIntent);
        }
        return views;
    }
}
```

And here is the widget layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#AA000000" android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageContentTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileNameTextView"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Problem:

The widget works just fine when the `allMessages` array has a length of zero: I set the text of the TextView to "There are no messages to show" and everyone is happy; when I have at least one message in the array, the code runs just fine, no exceptions, no nothing (I debugged it and everything) but when `onUpdate` returns, the emulator shows "Problem loading widget" on the home screen where the widget should be. It is also important to notice that the same exact code works just fine in Froyo and Gingerbread. Why am I not getting any exceptions if something is going wrong? The debugger runs the entire `onUpdate` method and returns just fine, but the widget wont load. Any ideas?

Comment: any luck regarding your issue?